# Interpretation of dummy variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data, linear-model, regression-coefficients

Lets say that i have linear regression $Y= a +XB$, and in my $X$ matrix i have a dummy for the gender, lets call it $d_{g}$ which is 1 for male and 0 for female. The coefficient $b$ of $d_{g}$ shows the effect of being male **relative** to the effect for being female. How can i get the effect of being female ? Or the effect of being male, but **not relative** to the female.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "the effect of being male, but not relative to the female"? Relative to what then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reconstruct what you want from your fit using the population fractions of male and female $f_M$ and $f_F = 1 - f_M$.

The expectation of $Y$ for males and females is given by:
$$ E[Y|M] = a + b \qquad E[Y|F] = a$$
so
$$ E[Y|M] - E[Y|F] = b$$
$b$ gives the expected change in $Y$ going from female to male, as you said in your post.

Given the male and female population fractions we can construct the unconditional expectation:
$$E[Y] = f_F E[Y|F] + f_M E[Y|M] = (1-f_M) a + f_M (a + b) = a + f_M b$$
and from that, we can get the expected change in $Y$ going from sex-unknown to male:
$$E[Y|M] - E[Y] = (1 - f_M) b$$
and, similarly, the expected change in $Y$ going from sex-unknown to female:
$$E[Y|F] - E[Y] = - f_M b$$
You should get the same results with this method as from the procedure suggested by Michael above, without having to re-run the regression.

Comment: +1, this is the better solution once the regression is already done.

Comment: (+1)  Wonder if that's the desired interpretation of "the effect of being male, but not relative to the female". (I can't think of another that makes any sense)

Comment: Thank you. @Scortchi I am sorry if it was not clear enough.

Comment: How could this be extended, in the case, that apart from Male Female, there was also a dummy for e.g rich/poor, and you wanted the effect of being male **regardless** of being rich/poor

Comment: @quant: You can extend it, but the algebra gets pretty harry. Suppose your model is $Y = a + b u + c v$, where $u = \{0, 1\}$ and $v = \{0, 1\}$ are your dummy variables for female/male and poor/rich, respectively. You can write fully conditional expectations $E[Y|0 0] = a, E[Y|1 0] = a+b, E[Y|0 1] = a+c, E[Y|1 1] = a + b + c$. Given the population fractions of each subgroup $p_{0 0}, p_{1 0}, p_{0 1}, p_{1 1}$, you can compute semi-conditional probabilities like $E[Y|1 .] = (p_{1 0} E[Y|1 0] + p_{1 1} E[Y| 1 1])/(p_{1 0} + p_{1 1}) = a + b + \frac{p_{1 1}}{p_{1 0} + p_{1 1}} c$

Comment: and unconditional probabilities like $E[Y|. .] = a + (p_{1 0} + p_{1 1}) b + (p_{0 1} + p_{1 1}) c$, and then take difference to get expected changes such as $E[Y|1 .] - E[Y|. .] = (p_{0 0} + p_{0 1}) b + \left[ \frac{p_{1 1}}{p_{1 0} + p_{1 1}} - (p_{0 1} + p_{1 1}) \right] c$. There may be some way to convert this to more compact matrix expressions; I don't know. If you are willing to re-do the regression, it would also be straightforward to fall back to Michael's suggested procedure.

Comment: @DavidWright Thank you. One last follow up question. So in The case that i have 2 dummies, Male/Female and Rich/Poor, and I code $d_{g}=1$ for Male, $d_{g}=0$ for Female, $d_{money}=1$ for rich and $d_{money}=0$ for poor, I will get 3 coefficients, a(intercept), b(for gender) and c(for money). Then if i re-run the regression and I code $d_{g}=0$ for Male, $d_{g}=1$ for Female, $d_{money}=1$ for rich and $d_{money}=0$ for poor, will **all** the coefficients change ? Also the intercept ?

Comment: @DavidWright how did will this approach of interpretation change, if i center the data before the regression ?

Answer (score 2):

This can simply be achieved by leaving out the constant (other wise you run in the so called dummy-trap) and using a model like
$$Y=d_{female} + d_{male} + X\beta + u, $$
where $d_{female}$ is one if female and $d_{male}$ is one if male.
Then you will have
$$E[Y|X,male]=d_{male} + E[X]\beta,$$
$$E[Y|X,female]=d_{female} + E[X]\beta$$

and $E[Y|X,male]-E[Y|X,female]=d_{male} -d_{female}$.